# Rcpp exercises given by Hadley Wickham

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

For the exercises given in the middle of [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html). I would like to know the answers...to check my understanding.

I'm not sure what R `base` functions these all are but here are my guesses:

`f1` is a function that calculates the sum of x_i / i from i = 1 to n where xi is the vector input to `f1` and n is the length of x

`f2` is the same as the `cumsum()` function in `base`

`f3` is the `any()` function in `base`

`f4` checks for the first member of the list that your pred function input returns a TRUE statement

`f5` gets the minimum value as you compare values for the vectors x and y (which can be of differing length)

And I think the answers of the second half the exercise are as follows (any efficiency improvements/suggestions are greatly welcome):

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
bool allC(LogicalVector x) {
  int n = x.size();

  for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (!(x[i])) {
      return false;
    } else {}
  }
  return true;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cumprodC(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n);

  out[0] = x[0];

  for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
    out[i] = out[i-1] *  x[i];
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cumminC(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n);

  out[0] = x[0];

  for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
    out[i] = std::min(out[i-1],x[i]);
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cummaxC(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n);

  out[0] = x[0];

  for(int i=1; i<n; i++){
    out[i] = std::max(out[i-1],x[i]);
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector diffC(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n-1);

  for(int i=0; i<(n-1); i++){
    out[i] = x[i+1]-x[i];
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector rangeC(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(2);

  out[0] = x[0];
  out[1] = x[0];

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    out[0] = std::min(out[0],x[i]);
    out[1] = std::max(out[1],x[i]);
  }
  return out;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double varC(NumericVector x){
  int n = x.size();
  double sum_of_x;
  double sum_of_sqr;

  sum_of_x = 0.0;
  sum_of_sqr = 0.0;

  for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    sum_of_x += x[i];
    sum_of_sqr += x[i]*x[i];
  }

  return (sum_of_sqr - (sum_of_x*sum_of_x)/n)/(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: For `f1` read the code again. It's not `sum of x_i / i`.

Comment: sorry I think i meant `cumulative sum of (x_i/i)` from i=1 to n where n is the length of x

Comment: @h.l.m It isn't a cumulative sum either. The name of the function should give you a bit of a hint.

Comment: ah! its `sum of x_i/n` not `i`

Comment: @h.l.m And that function got a specific name in statistics.

Comment: A note on `var`: you may run into size issues for very large vectors or large numbers (overflow).  That is why in the `mean` function, the division by `n` was moved inside the loop to calculate the sum.  Another approach would be to use logs to change multiplication of big numbers into addition of small numbers, but there are issues there with 0's and negative numbers that you have to worry about.